# Testing javascript click function capybara attach file image upload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to test a photo upload paperclip using Capybara. However I'm getting an error about file field when running cucumber test.

```
Unable to find file field :upload (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Javascript

```
$("#uploadhere").click(function() {
    $("#photo_upload_entry_upload").click();
  });
```

Steps.rb file

```
Then(/^I should see photo when I upload and submit entry$/) do
  script = "$('form.new_photo_upload_entry').css('i.fa.fa-file-image-o');"
  page.execute_script(script)

  fixture_path = Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', 'fixtures', 'test.jpg')

  within('form.new_photo_upload_entry') do 
    attach_file(:upload, fixture_path)
  end
end
```

HTML (using inspect element)

```
<input type="file" name="photo_upload_entry[upload]" id="photo_upload_entry_upload">
```

Ruby code of form in slim format

```
.entry-label STEP 1: UPLOAD YOUR IMAGE
    .entry-upload#uploadhere
      .upload-here
        i.fa.fa-file-image-o
        br
        = "UPLOAD YOUR IMAGE HERE"
      img
    =f.file_field :upload
```

Comment: Have you tried to see the name, class or id in the html for the file_field generated ? see how it is there and try to attach the file to a locator other than :upload to match the html.

Comment: I tried with using the selector name, id, type. They all threw element cannot be found error. `Unable to find file field "photo_upload_entry_upload" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`  `Unable to find file field "photo_upload_entry[upload]" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
attach_file(:upload, fixture_path)
```

is wrong. As i can see in your HTML, you'll have to use:

```
attach_file('photo_upload_entry[upload]', fixture_path)
```

as the `attach_file` works with the input field name

Comment: `Unable to find file field "photo_upload_entry[upload]" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/photo_upload_entries_new_steps.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: @fabersky Worked for me. Thanks! For hours, I've been trying to select the `input` with xpath with `//input[@id=...]`. I wonder why selection by name works and xpath doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `id` attribute of an input element, I think it'll be ok.

`page.attach_file('photo_upload_entry_upload', path_of_file)`

Comment: I tried it with id, doesn't work. `Unable to find file field "photo_upload_entry_upload" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`